# How to convert ISAPI related methods and structures to C#

Tags: pinvoke, dllimport, signature, isapi

I have an ISAPI filter written for IIS6. I now need to write a wrapper for IIS7 to wrap the IIS6 filter. I plan to write HTTP module in C# and Pinvoke the unmanaged dll methods.

I need C# representation of the following code,

```
DWORD WINAPI HttpFilterProc(
   PHTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT pfc,
   DWORD notificationType,
   LPVOID pvNotification
);

    typedef struct _HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT {
       DWORD cbSize;
       DWORD Revision;
       PVOID ServerContext;
       DWORD ulReserved;
       BOOL fIsSecurePort;
       PVOID pFilterContext;
       BOOL GetServerVariable;
       BOOL AddResponseHeaders;
       BOOL WriteClient;
       VOID * AllocMem;
       BOOL ServerSupportFunction;
    } HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT, * PHTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT;
```

I tried using PInvoke Assistant from codeplex but i am not able to make it work.
Has anyone done anything like this before?
Can anyone provide a solution to the above?

Correction: Correct structure added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the code in your answer you need to use the following:

```
[DllImport(@"XyzISAPI.dll")]
public static extern uint HttpFilterProc(
    ref HttpFilterContext pfc, 
    uint notificationType, 
    IntPtr pvNotification
);
```

The native code is passed a pointer to the context `struct` and passing the struct by `ref` is the easy way to match that. The final parameter is `LPVOID`, which is `void*` and that is plain `IntPtr` in managed code.

As for `HTTP_FILTER_ACCESS_DENIED`, define it like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HttpFilterAccessDenied
{
    IntPtr URL;
    IntPtr PhysicalPath;
    uint Reason;
}
```

You can then obtain one of those like this:

```
HttpFilterAccessDenied hfad = (HttpFilterAccessDenied)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
    pvNotification, typeof(HttpFilterAccessDenied));
```

And then you can get hold of the string values from the `struct` with `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` or `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the PInvokeStackImbalance exception at debugging. But i still have the pvNotification returned as Zero. I will check the other details and then update here.

Comment: `IntPtr.Zero` will be passed when there is nothing to be passed in the `pvNotification` parameter. You don't have enough reputation to up-vote, but you can accept.

Comment: I need to now figure out how to populate the HttpFilterContext (pfc) from the HttpApplication object..

Comment: OK, I don't think I can do any more in comments. I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Yes David, you did answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry David i was still trying to figure out how to do that. I also wanted to vote up.

Comment: I cant make it work. Although the original error was resolved. It throws "System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" now

Comment: Well I can't answer that in comments. For a start I don't understand your architecture. As I understand, you don't import `HttpFilterProc`, you implement it in a DLL and the IIS calls it. So I've really no idea what you are trying to do. It can't be a normal filter because everything is back to front.

Comment: The ISAPI agent DLL (XyzISAPI.dll) is already written for IIS6 but does not work in IIS7. So i am writing a new DLL (NewAgentISAPI.dll) for IIS7 using C# that would wrap the XyzISAPI.dll methods. So when IIS7 calls the NewAgent, the NewAgent would then internally call the Xyz dll. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: OK, I understand. But I still can't help. I think you need a new Q.